# Magento 2.3 InstallSchema.php does not create any table

Tags: database, magento2.3, table

I have an InstallSchema.php that does not create the table in the database.
Here is the code of the schema php:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\News\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        // Get news table
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('simplenews');
        // Check if the table already exists
        if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            // Create news table
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'title',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Title'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'summary',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Summary'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'description',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Description'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Created At'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                    'Status'
                )
                ->setComment('News Table')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I know I'm not the first one to have this issue, so I tried everything I could find about this. Here is what I have done to try make it works.

Before every try, executing sql

```
Delete from setup_module where module like '%module_name%';
```

I have of course checked that the query worked properly.

I have tried to install it with ***UpgradeSchema.php*** and change the version of the module in

```
magento/app/code/MyVendor/module/etc/module.xml (from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1),
```

it didn't work.

I have also tried to install it with ***Recurring.php***

I'm using the command

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

to install the table in the database. This command display no error and i can see my module in the output of the command.

I have also tried

```
setup:di:compile
```

to see any errors, but can't find any errors.

I had no problem installing magento, everything looks good so I'm lost.

> EDIT : My module is active (I checked it with ***sudo php bin/magento
>   module:status***)

Comment: you can i also  delete your table from database

Comment: you mean delete the setup_module table from my database?

Comment: @ChristopheS you made this mistake : 'primary' => true, you forget to put comma after true

Comment: simplenews table remove from database.

Comment: The problem is that the table is not created by the script at all, this is what I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: If you delete record from setup_module table, you should flush the cache too. If version is upgraded, you can share UpgradeSchema.php code in the question.

Comment: It didn't work, I'm only using InstallSchema.php to install my table, i tried with UpgradeSchema.php and Recurring.php to see if it would change anything, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was wrong, my folders had a lowercase name, so in my install schema neither with

```
namespace Vendor\News\Setup;
```

or with

```
namespace vendor\news\setup;
```

the install function were called when i was doing the upgrade command. I just had to replace the first letter of my folders with uppercase and then change my namespace to

```
namespace Vendor\News\Setup;
```

Now, everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        // Get news table
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('simplenews');
        // Check if the table already exists
        if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            // Create news table
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true,
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'title',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Title'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'summary',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Summary'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'description',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Description'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Created At'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                    'Status'
                )
                ->setComment('News Table')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

your code is running perfectly i used and table is created.

[image]

Please make you sure you run magento command at right place and delete row from **setup_module** table and also check your table is exist or not. code is working.

Please check which database are you used ??

After php bin/magento setup:upgrade run this command you can see your module name ?? ( Terminal/putty )

Check you run your running magento not Other Magentos ??

Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command before delete row from Setup_module table.

Run **php bin/magento module:s**

You can check your module status and if it is disable then run this command

```
php bin/magento module:e Modulename_VendoreName
```

And again run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: I have no idea what to do, I'm 100% sure I'm removing the right row from setup_module, I'm using the command from my magento root directory

Comment: @ChristopheS  answer is updat please check and let me inform your table is created or not ??

Comment: I have only one magento, I'm using the database "magento", this is a fresh installation of magento, I can see my module name after running bin/magento setup:upgrade. What I do before upgrading is 1) checking if the table was created or not 2) if not remove my module from setup_module 3) run the command bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Have you check Module is Enable or not ?? Using above command which mension in above answer.

Comment: Yes I have checked it's active

Comment: Some Time module.xml  define with intiallly disabled . Please check Module.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyVendor_module-news" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
Everything looks good i think

Comment: I have also tried to use logger to see if the function Install were call, I used $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Installation of table : simplenews');
but I was not able to find the file either in my /var/log/ directory or my magento/var/log directory.